# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow - need to add item to another list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I've created a new list. When someone books travel on my first list and they are also in the group with permission on the new list I need the travel information added to the new list.

The workflow I have now for the travel list doesn't appear to have the option of adding the same information to the new list. There is a dropdown with multiple list choices but none are the new list I've created.

Is this not possible? Has someone seen a tutorial?

Comment: I've tried the calendar overlay but it doesn't allow me to filter for only the users with permission to the new list

Comment: **Off topic** _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 0):

If the second list is in a different site collection than the first list, you will need to use a Web Service Call in order to update the second list.

Comment: Can you show an example to make this an answer rather than a comment?